# Which technology its better to make a voice chat: Cirrus, FMS or XMPP?

Tags: xmpp, chat, p2p, flash-media-server, adobe-cirrus

I am searching for a good technology to develop a voice chat, until now, the best I found are:

- Cirrus (Adobe)
- Flash Media Server (Adobe)
- XMPP

But all have good and bad features. i.e.:

- Cirrus runs only in the adobe servers `rmtfp://example.adobe.com`, is that reliable?, what will happen if some day adobe fall down?
- FMS it good, but I must pay -*_*-
- XMPP it good too, but I cant found reliable information for developing something. And zero information about voice chat.

Do you know some good tech to develop this type of app?

Comment: i think FMS is preferred generally. Because in future if you wanna convert voice chat into video chat, then FMS admin is having a lot of advanced functions to control it.

Comment: tried Session Initiation Protocol (SIP)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest generally a media server, because it's a thing that you control (so better than cirrus) and because it's designed for streaming media (so better than xmpp)
However i'm not sure about fms, take a look at [red5](http://www.red5.org/) (which is opensource) and [wowza](http://www.wowza.com/pricing)